# Kafka Event Receiver JAAS error

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

We are getting the following error when trying to set up a kafka event receiver from DAS. DAS is running on amazon ec2 and kafka is running off of eventador.io.

We have tried using the modules for the following versions found in kafka server

Versions

```
2.10_0.8.2.1
2.10_0.10.1
2.10_0.10.2
```

Modules

```
kafka.jar
kafka-clients.jar
metrics-core.jar
scala-libray.jar
zkclient.jar
zookeeper.jar
```

We have the following jass.conf file located in DAS/repository/conf/identity

```
KafkaClient {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required debug=true
    useKeyTab=true
    storeKey=true
    serviceName="kafka"
    keyTab="$keytab-location"
    principal="client@EXAMPLE.COM";
};

KafkaServer {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required debug=true
    useKeyTab=true
    storeKey=true
    serviceName="kafka"
    keyTab="$keytab-location"
    principal="kafka/localhost@EXAMPLE.COM";
};
```

Error we are getting

```
> TID[-1234] [DAS] [2017-04-19 01:20:36,150] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.admin.EventReceiverAdminService} -
> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Exception while loading
> Zookeeper JAAS login context 'Client'
> org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.EventReceiverDeployer.processDeployment(EventReceiverDeployer.java:237)
> org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.EventReceiverDeployer.executeManualDeployment(EventReceiverDeployer.java:273)
> org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.util.helper.EventReceiverConfigurationFileSystemInvoker.saveAndDeploy(EventReceiverConfigurationFileSystemInvoker.java:98)
> org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.util.helper.EventReceiverConfigurationFileSystemInvoker.save(EventReceiverConfigurationFileSystemInvoker.java:81)
> org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.util.helper.EventReceiverConfigurationFileSystemInvoker.encryptAndSave(EventReceiverConfigurationFileSystemInvoker.java:76)
> org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.CarbonEventReceiverService.deployEventReceiverConfiguration(CarbonEventReceiverService.java:76)
> org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.admin.EventReceiverAdminService.deployJsonEventReceiverConfiguration(EventReceiverAdminService.java:619)
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
> org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
> org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
> org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
> org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
> org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
> org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
> org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
> org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
> org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
> org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
> org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.stub.EventReceiverAdminServiceStub.deployJsonEventReceiverConfiguration(EventReceiverAdminServiceStub.java:3404)
> org.apache.jsp.eventreceiver.add_005fevent_005freceiver_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(add_005fevent_005freceiver_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:354) org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
> org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
> org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
> org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
> org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
> org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I tried reproducing the same locally using kafka_2.10-0.10.2.0 and 2.10_0.8.2.1. But it worked perfectly without any issues. May be the issue is  with the zk version that eventador.io is using. Can you please check that. And also try to use 2.10_0.8.2.1 without the "jaas.conf", it should work too.